# Proxy chain in Windows XP

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-xp

At work I have to access the Internet through a proxy. 
I have the proxy set on the LAN:

[image: screenshot of Windows XP LAN settings, in Spanish/Portuguese]

The problem is that the proxy filters high traffic sites like YouTube. Sometimes I need to use some of these sites and I access them through "anonymizer proxies" or Tor Browser.

Can I set up a proxy chain to use for specific sites only? For example:

> YouTube → Internet proxy → My work proxy → Internet

For other sites, I'd use my normal work proxy only.

Answer (score -1):

Try this – Windows platform proxy chaining:

> [Sockschain](http://ufasoft.com/socks/) is a program that allows to work with any Internet service through a chain of SOCKS or HTTP proxies to hide the real IP-address. SocksChain can function as a usual SOCKS-server that transmits queries through a chain of proxies. SocksChain can be used with client programs that do not support the SOCKS protocol, but work with one TCP-connection, such as TELNET, HTTP, IRC... (FTP uses 2 connections). And your IP-address will not be seen in the server's logs or mail headers;

[image: screenshot of SocksChain in use]

Comment: @Hashim: We all appreciate your willingness and eagerness to help with a community project, but please be more careful. On this one, you broke the link to the web site.

Comment: Damn. Sorry about that. I'll be more careful... and get some sleep while I'm at it.